# What does this Eclipse 4.9.0 Icon at project-elements mean?

Tags: eclipse, git, icons, egit

I already took a look at the [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) but did not find this icon:

[image]

Does it say something about git-related information, since that is a project connected to a git repo. The status of the local repository is updated, since I recently used git pull on the project.

Does it show some other git-related status?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This means the resource (Project, Folder, File) is checked in to some source control system such as Git, SVN, CVS, using the 'Team' menus.

Comment: I found some information in the [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State) about the icon decoration, but it is still a little bit confusing. The label seems to mark resources, which are tracked according to the settings in Eclipse: Window > Preferences > Team > Git > Label Decorations > Tab Icon Decorations > only ticking checkbox 'Tracked resources' enables the yellow icon, do you mean 'tracked' by 'checked in'

Comment: @Marius The terminology varies depending on the source control system you are using. For SVN it is checked in, I don't use Git so I can't say what the term is. The icon just means the code is being managed by whatever SCS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When using **Git** the icon means that the folder contains one or more files that have been committed once before (and does not only contain files that have all been excluded via `.gitignore`. In short, **the folder contains at least one tracked file**.

Please note, Git does not track folders (e. g. in contrast to SVN which uses the same icons with a slightly different meaning), but only files, so the icon refers to the files the folder contains and not to the folder itself.

See also:

- ***Window > Preferences: Team > Git > Label Decorations***
- [EGit User Guide - Icon Decorations](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations)